# python ImportError: bad magic number in 'collections': b'3\r\r\n'

Tags: python, pip, libraries

I decompyled a .pyc file with decompyle3. Now when I'm try to run the python script it returns me this error:

```
File "server_eolstep2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flask_restful import Api
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from functools import wraps, partial
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: bad magic number in 'collections': b'3\r\r\n'
```

I'm using python 3.7.0
I yet installed flask_restful but I don't know the kind of this error.

ps I removed the name of the folder before Appdata.